# DDD implementation with Spring Data and JPA + Hibernate problem with identities

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, domain-driven-design

So I'm trying for the first time in a not so complex project to implement Domain Driven Design by separating all my code into **application**, **domain**, **infrastructure** and **interfaces** packages.

I also went with the whole separation of the JPA Entities to Domain models that will hold my business logic as rich models and used the Builder pattern to instantiate. This approach created me a headache and can't figure out if Im doing it all wrong when using JPA + ORM and Spring Data with DDD.

**Process explanation**
The application is a Rest API consumer (without any user interaction) that process daily through Scheduler tasks a fairly big amount of data resources and stores or updates into MySQL. Im using RestTemplate to fetch and convert the JSON responses into Domain objects and from there Im applying any business logic within the Domain itself e.g. validation, events, etc

From what I have read the aggregate root object should have an identity in their whole lifecycle and should be unique. I have used the id of the rest API object because is already something that I use to identify and track in my business domain. I have also created a property for the Technical id so when I convert Entities to Domain objects it can hold a reference for the update process.

When I need to persist the Domain to the data source (MySQL) for the first time Im converting them into Entity objects and I persist them using the `save()` method. So far so good.

Now when I need to update those records in the data source I first fetch them as a List of Employees from data source, convert Entity objects to Domain objects and then I fetch the list of Employees from the rest API as Domain models. Up until now I have two lists of the same Domain object types as `List<Employee>`. I'm iterating them using Streams and checking if an objects are not `equal()` between them if yes a collection of List items is created as a third list with Employee objects that need to be updated. Here I've already passed the technical Id to the domain objects in the third list of Employees so Hibernate can identify and use to update the records that are already exists.

Up to here are all fairly simple stuff until I use the `saveAll()` method to update the records.

**Questions**

- I alway see Hibernate using INSERT instead of updating the list of
  records. So If Im correct Hibernate session is not recognising the
  objects that Im throwing into it because I have detached them when I
  used the convert to domain object?
- Does anyone have a better idea how can I implement this differently or fix
  this problem?
- Or should I stop using this approach as two different objects and continue use
  them as rich Entity models?

*Simple classes to explain it with code*

**EmployeeDO.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "employees")
public class EmployeeDO implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    public EmployeeDO() {}

    ...omitted getter/setters
}
```

**Employee.java**

```
public class Employee {

    private Long persistId;
    private Long employeeId;

    private String name;

    private Employee() {}

    ...omitted getters and Builder
}
```

**EmployeeConverter.java**

```
public class EmployeeConverter {

    public static EmployeeDO serialize(Employee employee) {
        EmployeeDO target = new EmployeeDO();

        if (employee.getPersistId() != null) {
          target.setId(employee.getPersistId());
        }

        target.setName(employee.getName());

        return target;
    }

    public static Employee deserialize(EmployeeDO employee) {
        return new Country.Builder(employee.getEmployeeId)
                .withPersistId(employee.getId()) //<-- Technical ID setter
                .withName(employee.getName())
                .build();
    }
}
```

**EmployeeRepository.java**

```
@Component
public class EmployeeReporistoryImpl implements EmployeeRepository {

    @Autowired
    EmployeeJpaRepository db;

    @Override
    public List<Employee> findAll() {
        return db.findAll().stream()
                .map(employee -> EmployeeConverter.deserialize(employee))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    @Override
    public void saveAll(List<Employee> employees) {
        db.saveAll(employees.stream()
                .map(employee -> EmployeeConverter.serialize(employee))
                .collect(Collectors.toList()));

    }

}
```

**EmployeeJpaRepository.java**

```
@Repository
public interface EmployeeJpaRepository extends JpaRepository<EmployeeDO, Long> {

}
```

Answer (score 3):

I use the same approach on my project: two different models for the domain and the persistence.

First, I would suggest you to don't use the converter approach but use the [Memento](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/memento_pattern.htm) pattern. Your domain entity exports a memento object and it could be restored from the same object. Yes, the domain has 2 functions that aren't related to the domain (they exist just to supply a non-functional requirement), but, on the other side, you avoid to expose functions, getters and constructors that the domain business logic never use.

For the part about the persistence, I don't use JPA exactly for this reason: you have to write a lot of code to reload, update and persist the entities correctly. I write directly SQL code: I can write and test it fast, and once it works I'm sure that it does what I want. With the Memento object I can have directly what I will use in the insert/update query, and I avoid myself a lot of headaches about the JPA of handling complex tables structures.

Anyway, if you want to use JPA, the only solution is to:

- load the *persistence* entities and transform them into *domain* entities
- update the *domain* entities according to the changes that you have to do in your domain
- save the *domain* entities, that means:

  - reload the *persistence* entities
  - change, or create if there're new ones, them with the changes that you get from the updated *domain* entities
  - save the *persistence* entities

I've tried a mixed solution, where the *domain* entities are extended by the *persistence* ones (a bit complex to do). A lot of care should be took to avoid that *domain* model should adapts to the restrictions of JPA that come from the *persistence* model.

[Here](https://www.mehdi-khalili.com/orm-anti-patterns-part-4-persistence-domain-model) there's an interesting reading about the splitting of the two models.

Finally, my suggestion is to think how complex the domain is and use the simplest solution for the problem:

- is it big and with a lot of complex behaviours? Is expected that it will grow up in a big one? Use two models, *domain* and *persistence*, and manage the persistence directly with SQL It avoids a lot of caos in the read/update/save phase.
- is it simple? Then, first, should I use the DDD approach? If really yes, I would let the JPA annotations to split inside the *domain*. Yes, it's not pure DDD, but we live in the real world and the time to do something **simple** in the pure way should not be some orders of magnitude bigger that the the time I need to to it with some compromises. And, on the other side, I can write all this stuff in an XML in the infrastructure layer, avoiding to clutter the *domain* with it. As it's done in the spring DDD sample [here](https://github.com/citerus/dddsample-core).

Answer (score 0):

When you want to update an existing object, you first have to load it through `entityManager.find()` and apply the changes on that object or use `entityManager.merge` since you are working with detached entities.

Anyway, modelling rich domain models based on JPA is the perfect use case for [Blaze-Persistence Entity Views](https://github.com/Blazebit/blaze-persistence#entity-view-usage).

Blaze-Persistence is a query builder on top of JPA which supports many of the advanced DBMS features on top of the JPA model. I created Entity Views on top of it to allow easy mapping between JPA models and custom interface defined models, something like Spring Data Projections on steroids. The idea is that you define your target structure the way you like and map attributes(getters) via JPQL expressions to the entity model. Since the attribute name is used as default mapping, you mostly don't need explicit mappings as 80% of the use cases is to have DTOs that are a subset of the entity model.

The interesting point here is that entity views can also be updatable and support automatic translation back to the entity/DB model.
A mapping for your model could look as simple as the following

```
@EntityView(EmployeeDO.class)
@UpdatableEntityView
interface Employee {
    @IdMapping("persistId")
    Long getId();
    Long getEmployeeId();
    String getName();
    void setName(String name);
}
```

Querying is a matter of applying the entity view to a query, the simplest being just a query by id.

`Employee dto = entityViewManager.find(entityManager, Employee.class, id);`

The Spring Data integration allows you to use it almost like Spring Data Projections: https://persistence.blazebit.com/documentation/entity-view/manual/en_US/index.html#spring-data-features and it can also be saved back. Here a sample repository

```
@Repository
interface EmployeeRepository {
  Employee findOne(Long id);
  void save(Employee e);
}
```

It will only fetch the mappings that you tell it to fetch and also only update the state that you make updatable through setters.

With the Jackson integration you can deserialize your payload onto a loaded entity view or you can avoid loading alltogether and use the Spring MVC integration to capture just the state that was transferred and flush that. This could look like the following:

```
@RequestMapping(path = "/employee/{id}", method = RequestMethod.PUT, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<String> updateEmp(@EntityViewId("id") @RequestBody Employee emp) {
    employeeRepository.save(emp);

    return ResponseEntity.ok(emp.getId().toString());
}
```

Here you can see an example project: https://github.com/Blazebit/blaze-persistence/tree/master/examples/spring-data-webmvc

Comment: Sorry, but it looks that with your solution the annotation of JPA and Blaze-Persistence Entity Views should be used in both the Entities. While your project is for sure extremely useful (not a joke, I could use it somewhere, in the future - I've never seen it before), here the questions are different.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your statement "should be used in both the Entities".

Comment: Entity Views become your domain model which map back to entities through the entity view mapping annotations. There are quite a few companies already that successfully developed an efficient domain model layer with entity views. Entity views are "aware" if the entity needs persisting or updating and supports efficient dirty state flushing. It will relieve you from many of the pain points usually encountered when developing a domain model approach on top of JPA. As far as I understand, you wanted to know why there is an insert which I explained in the first sentence.

Comment: My point was that, in the somewhere in the domain you still use the JPA annotations to map the entity. That's also something unclear from your example, how the EmployeeDO is managed: are there annotations? Is simply the class "understood" from the framework and correctly mapped to the Employee? Here the question is how to map a class that is totally unaware of the persistence layer to a class that is managed by JPA, hence part of the persistence layer. Up to now there's no simple solution for this with JPA, because JPA itself requires to be part of the model.

Comment: ... That's exactly what, wo designs within the DDD rules, tries to avoid. In the domain model no dependencies from the infrastructure layer should exists. Hence, the domain entities should (ideally) be POJOs, that the objects of the infrastructure layer take (without changing them) for persisting them. If you annotate the domain POJOs with JPA, or Blaze-Persistence annotation, you leave part of the persistence be part of the domain. Anyway, as I wrote in my answer, not always the ideal solutions are better. Deals should be done, and different options exists.

Comment: I understand what you are saying but how else would you define such an external mapping? Via XML e.g. the JPA orm.xml? Or manage the objects manually?
At the end of the day you still want to know how this thing works and having external mapping logic only makes this harder. That's the reason annotations are so popular, you can do such configurations inline, just where it applies. If you are a purist and absolutely want to separate things you are probably gonna waste a lot of time and I doubt that such an approach is more maintainable. And after all, annotations are metadata.

Comment: That's exactly how is done in the DDD sample linked in my answer. And that's exactly why is simpler to work, within a DDD project, with a non relational DB. It's not about being a purist, but with a big domain with a complex logic having to deal also with the JPA details (lazy loading, sub queries, counting...) is not funny. About the fact that the annotations are used everywhere in the domain (domain model, I mean), it doesn't mean that it's always the best solution. ;) I also see a lot @Autowired on private fields, and it's for sure a bad practice (try to test such a class).